# eventlistener without anonymous function

Tags: javascript, scope, addeventlistener

Attempting to use pure JavaScript to find the length of text in a textbox. Why is it that the verbose method of:

```js
var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname");
first_name.addEventListener("change", howLong(first_name));

function howLong(first_name) {
  var p = first_name.value.length;
  alert("Length of input is " + p);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="firstname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" /> </form>
```

does not allow the value to be accessed (always zero), while the use of anonymous function

```js
var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname");
  first_name.addEventListener("change", function(){
  var p = first_name.value.length;
  alert("Length of input is "+p);
  } );
```

```html
<form>
<input id="firstname" type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/> </form>
```

Works correctly?

Comment: because the first one is calling the method and storing what it returns to the event handler. So your code is really
`howLong(first_name);
first_name.addEventListener("change", undefined);` Did you not notice the alert when the page loaded and you did not change anything? A lightbulb should have gone off. :)

Comment: @epascarello it did, hence the question, so I could get a definitive answer, and not merely guess at such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want yo pass the function itself `howLong` and not call the function and pass the result. Working code:

```js
var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname");
first_name.addEventListener("change", howLong); // instead of howLong(first_name)

function howLong() {
  var p = first_name.value.length;
  alert("Length of input is " + p);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="firstname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" /> </form>
```

As @Andreas stated it would be better to use `this` in the function and not rely on a global variable since this gives you better flexibility (for example you can use this same function for other inputs):

```js
var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname");
first_name.addEventListener("change", howLong); // instead of howLong(first_name)

function howLong() {
  
  var p = this.value.length;
  alert("Length of input is " + p);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="firstname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" /> </form>
```

Comment: Thanks - I will accept this answer when SO will allow me

Comment: Yep, this is a good advice but I tried to just address the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the return value of howLong(first_name) to addEventListener rather than the function itself. One possible fix:

```
first_name.addEventListener("change", () => howLong(first_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `howLong` function is being executed at runtime and therefore returns the value `0` because nothing has been typed into the `input` yet.
What you need to do is to pass in the function itself:

```js
var first_name = document.getElementById("firstname");
    first_name.addEventListener("change", () => howLong(first_name));

function howLong(first_name) {
  var p = first_name.value.length;
  alert("Length of input is " + p);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="firstname" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```